# What is the ultimate ASP.NET Webforms Architecture

Tags: asp.net, ajax, architecture, webforms

i have very strict requirements for performance on a large data entry application. You can imagine a single form with hundreds of fields, tabs, modal popups and similar.

The question is, what is the best Ajax architecture that i can implement to make it fast?

i was thinking about lightweight json async calls on the client, and async operations on the server. I was also considering HTML templates on the client, instead of building html on the server.

Let me know what you think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Fast" is not a requirement. A requirement must be SMART (Specific, Measurable, Attainable, Relevant and Time-bound). So what must the maximum response time exactly be? How many concurrent users will the system have? If you exact the number of users will grow rapidly over time, pick an architecture that lets you scale out (add more servers) easily instead of needing to scale up (adding more power to a single server).

Comment: When i said fast, i thought primarly about rendering speed in the browser. The application will be used by 200-300 concurrent users, and it will not grow rapidly, at least in the first year. The response time must be under 2 seconds.

Comment: I *wish* these were my demanding requirements :-/

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of jQuery and HTML for the client and .net methods in the server-side callbacks. Async calls are good, but not always the best choice, remember that. Basically, use as few server-side components as possible because it generates much markup

there are also techinques for improving performance like caching. This can be done many places, for example on the .aspx page or on the web-server itself.

If you can, turn off the viewstate. This can generate much unnecessary markup

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of JQuery ajax and ASP.NET MVC 3. These two combined provide an easy way to make fully async applications and due to the nature of MVC you can have HTML templates, most of which are already available through the MVC3 template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I hate to say it.. but what you want is impossible.  You cannot have a form with hudreds of elements on it, and still have it perform well.  Of course "perform well" is subjective.. but the only way to get good performance over a high latency network connection with variable bandwidth (like the internet) is to work with very small sets of elements.

Comment: Although he hasn't said it is an internet application as such. It may be, but it is quite possible it may be only operating in a LAN environment, in which case, the variable bandwidth issue would not apply as much. In our company we have a huge data entry web app, but it is not accessed via the internet, but rather on a LAN.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but requirements are very strict and i can't change them. That is why i asked this question on stackoverflow, so let's get at least a good enough solution :)

Comment: You're still asking for the sky.  You want to move a freight train of data, but you want it as fast as Formula 1 racecar.  You say you have strict requirements, but it's impossible for anyone to help given how unspecific you've been.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AJAX-Enabled WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552.aspx), JQuery and [JQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) can give you a good network throughput performance and a good user experience for your users.

But this comes with a price. Developing, debugging and mantaining such an application is very hard considered to a regularly developed ASP.NET application.

It's a trade-off, and if you ask me I would suggest you to go for the traditional way and make some improvements to your application interface, such as dividing forms, implementing a save-continue wizard-like type input screens. You can still use JQuery to improve user experience and caching to improve application performance. Keeping an eye on view-state and using UpdatePanel's as necessary could help even more.